# Where did my data go?

Tags: r, type-conversion

head(AustinPulse)
   # A tibble: 6 x 149

```
Respondent Employed  StayHome   R1_Cost Gender

           <int>       <int>    <fct>    <int>               
1         1        2      1        1       1                                                            
2         1        2      1        1       2                                                             
3         2        2      1        1       1                                                               
4         1        2      1        0       1
```

My gender variable used to be an integer type. I made my gender variable into a factor by using the following code

### Code to convert to factor

```
AustinParents$Gender      = factor(AustinParents$Gender, levels = c(1, 2, 3, 4), labels = c("Male", "Female", "Prefer Not to say", "Other"))
```

## This is the summary after conversion

```
summary(AustinParents$Gender)
         Male            Female Prefer Not to say             Other              NA's 
            0                 0                 0                 0               392
```

In the rows I still see Female, Male, etc. Can someone tell me what I did wrong? More importantly, can you tell me how to fix it?  The same issue came up with my Race variable. All the other variables were fine.

I see this in the row and columns in the viewer

Respondent Employed  StayHome   R1_Cost Gender

```
           <int>       <int>    <fct>    <fct>               
1         1        2      1        1       Male                                                           
2         1        2      1        1       Female                                                             
3         2        2      1        1       Male                                                               
4         1        2      1        0       Male  


dput(AustinPulse$Gender[1:10])
structure(c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_), .Label = c("Male", "Female", "Prefer Not to say", 
"Other"), class = "factor")
```

Comment: i have created a dummy data similar to yours i have used as.factor(AustinParents$Gender) it worked fine. Done specify labels it will automatically convert it

Comment: Hi Hunaidkhan, I used this code AustinPulse$Gender = as.factor(AustinPulse$Gender)
> summary(AustinPulse$Gender)
             Male            Female Prefer Not to say             Other              NA's 
                0                 0                 0                 0               392

Comment: As you can see, I am still getting 0s for the levels? Will i have to upload the CSV?

Comment: What do you get when you run `class(AustinParents$Gender)`?

Comment: Something like this happens if the original vector does not contain values corresponding to the specified levels. Please add the output of dput(AustinPulse$Gender[1:10]) prior to using factor to your question.

Comment: What is the output of `unique(AustinParents$Gender)`?

Comment: Salman i get class(AustinParents$Gender)
[1] "factor"

Comment: Rui i get [1] <NA>
Levels:

Comment: No, I mean *before* coercion. (Tip: to ping a user start the username with '@' as in @Rui.)

Comment: Roland my code should be the following?  dput(AustinPulse$Gender[1:10]) = factor(AustinPulse$Gender)

Comment: No, what @Roland is asking you to do is to **edit the question** with the output of `dput(AustinPulse$Gender[1:10])`. Also, try to run the same `as.factor` instruction without the `levels` argument.

Comment: @Roland i added the dput statement. is that what you instructed?

Comment: @RuiBarradas here is the output AustinPulse$Gender = as.factor(AustinPulse$Gender)
> summary(AustinPulse$Gender)
             Male            Female Prefer Not to say             Other              NA's 
                0                 0                 0                 0               392

Comment: Yes, it would be but you would need to add the output of `dput` of the original data, before running `as.factor`, for us to see what was going on. In the mean time there is an accepted answer, problem solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works well for me when i remove the `levels`:

Given that `Gender` is :

```
Gender<-c("Male","Male","Male","Female","Female",
          "Prefer Not to say","Prefer Not to say",
          "Other","Other")
```

Then it works with:

```
Gender      <- factor(Gender,                     
                      labels = c("Male", "Female", "Prefer Not to say", "Other"))


summary(Gender)
```

Comment: your solution works, I can add in the actual values into the workspace and then run the code. thank you !